# iPhone sdk facebook login issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made an application which uses latest ios facebook sdk to connect. I also had facebook application installed on my iPhone. The problem is that when I am already logged in the facebook application. I cannot log in my application with facebook, because it takes me to facebook application where it says you are already authorized, but my app does not work.

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a function in facebook.m comment out this line.

```
didOpenOtherApp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbAppUrl]];
```